# What ports I have to open to make Exchange work on the WAN?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003

For accessing Exchange from the WAN, like smartphones, and laptops, what ports I have to open?
I googled, and I found an huge list of ports... i have to open all of them??

My exchange is 2003 version

Answer (score 2):

You have to use RPC/HTTPS aka Exchange Anywhere, you'll only have to open the 80 and/or 443 ports according to your IIS setup.

For using HTTPS you'll have to deploy the server and CA certificates to your clients.

See [this article](http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Implementing-RPC-over-HTTPS-single-Exchange-Server-2003-environment.html) on how to implement RPC/HTTPS in Exchange 2003

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If your are using SSL for OWA, Active Sync and RPC over HTTP then the only port you need open is 443. If your not using SSL obviously you will need port 80.

You will also need to open up ports for other exchange services if you need them, such as SMTP(25), POP3(110), IMAP(143) etc.

Answer (score 1):

For Outlook Clients and Windows Mobile phones you only need port 443

Answer (score 1):

Mail from other domains will use SMTP to arrive on port TCP 25.  HTTP or HTTP w/SSL needs to be allowed to accessed if you want phones and Outlook Web Access or Outlook over HTTP/s.  This is configurable but the default is TCP 443